# Use `nc` to create a http server that responds with a 400 and a json response message

Tags: python-3.x, netcat, http-status-code-400

I would like to create a simple server using `nc` or `python -m SimpleHttpServer` that would throw a 400 and send a JSON response which I could use to test error handling. I've tried `httpbin.org/status/400` but that only comes back with a status code but no response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
while true; do { echo -e "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\n\n{\"foo\": \"bar\"}"; } | nc -l 8080; done
```